# Frequent timeout errors from Azure ServiceBus

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

Using [Azure SDK example code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/typescript/src/sendMessages.ts) as inspiration I have coded a publishing function that sends a message to the specified queue name.

```
export const publisher = async (message: ServiceBusMessage, queueName: string) => {
  let sbClient, sender;

  try {
    sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(SB_CONNECTION_STRING);
    sender = sbClient.createSender(queueName);
    await sender.sendMessages([message]);
    await sender.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`[Service Bus] error sending message ${queueName}`, err);
    console.log("retrying message publish...");
    publisher(message, queueName);
  } finally {
    await sbClient.close();
  }
};
```

Most of the time this code works flawlessly but occasionally the connection times out and I retry sending within the catch block which seems to work all the time.

The message I'm sending are quite small:

```
{ 
  body: { 
    type: PROCESS_FILE, 
    data: { type: CURRENT, directory: PENDING_DIRECTORY } 
  }
}
```

And example of the log output that includes the thrown error by the Azure SDK:

```
 [08/03/2022 12:40:55.191] [LOG]      [X] Processed task
 [08/03/2022 12:40:55.346] [LOG]      [X] Processed task
 [08/03/2022 12:40:55.545] [LOG]      [X] Processed task
 [08/03/2022 12:41:27.840] [LOG]    [Service Bus] error sending message local.importer.process { ServiceBusError: ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 40.127.7.243:5671
     at translateServiceBusError (/usr/share/app/node_modules/@azure/service-bus/src/serviceBusError.ts:174:12)
     at MessageSender.open (/usr/share/app/node_modules/@azure/service-bus/src/core/messageSender.ts:304:31)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
   name: 'MessagingError',
   retryable: false,
   address: '40.127.7.243',
   code: 'GeneralError',
   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
   port: 5671,
   syscall: 'connect' }
 [08/03/2022 12:41:27.840] [LOG]    retrying message publish...
 [08/03/2022 12:41:28.756] [LOG]      [X] Processed task
```

I am not sure on how to proceed. Azure documentation recommends that you retry the message in the case of a timeout which I am doing however the timeouts are so frequent that it concerns me.

Does any kind soul have some insight into this from previous experience? I am using `"@azure/service-bus": "^7.3.0",`

Comment: Are you recreating the client/sender for each attempt to publish?  From the snippet, it looks like you may be but we're missing the larger context for how that fits into your application.   Would you also tell us a bit more about the host environment for your application?

Comment: You can download the `psping` utility and run it with the arguments mentioned to check if there is any network issue. See [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-troubleshooting-guide#connectivity-certificate-or-timeout-issues)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I have already tried using `psping` and I get 100% passes each time, even when setting tries to larger values

Comment: @JesseSquire yes, the client/sender are being created on each attempt to publish so I might need to close the current client and sender before attempting a retry. That being said there are instances (like today) where there has been no timeouts at all. Very frustrating.

Comment: @JesseSquire The host environment in question is a docker instance running `node:10.13-alpine`. The code is in Typescript and being executed using ts-node v10.6.0. The publisher function is triggered during an import process that consumes ~3000 files and queues updates for disparate systems. Not every file triggers an update.

Comment: Can you enable debug info as described in the *Troubleshooting* section in [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus) service-bus npm package page?

Comment: @DavidFaux:  I'm not sure that I fully understand the end-to-end, but it would seem that you're creating/closing the producer frequently, which would potentially impact the network, especially in a constrained environment.   We recommend creating the client and sender once and then caching them as a singleton for the lifetime of your application.   I suspect that may help alleviate the timeouts in this case.